# Using columns from query in subquery in Athena

Tags: sql, amazon-web-services, amazon-athena, presto, trino

I have the following query

```
SELECT 
  t1.id,
  t1.year, 
  t1.month, 
  t1.day,
  (CASE WHEN (NOT (t1.id IN (SELECT DISTINCT t2.id
                             FROM table2 t2
                             WHERE (to_date(cast(t2.year as varchar) || LPAD(cast(t2.month as varchar), 2, '0') || LPAD(cast(t2.day as varchar), 2, '0'),'yyyyMMdd') 
                                 BETWEEN (to_date(cast(t1.year as varchar) || LPAD(cast(t1.month as varchar), 2, '0') || LPAD(cast(t1.day as varchar), 2, '0'),'yyyyMMdd') - INTERVAL  '12' MONTH) 
                                   AND to_date(cast(t1.year as varchar) || LPAD(cast(t1.month as varchar), 2, '0') || LPAD(cast(t1.day as varchar), 2, '0'),'yyyyMMdd'))))) THEN 'Something' ELSE 'Something else' END) action
FROM
table1 t1
```

Now the problem is I am using t1.year, t1.month, t1.day inside the subquery but athena throws me

`Given correlated subquery is not supported`

How can I access the columns from main query in the subquery without getting the error in Athena?

Comment: `varchar` is not a permitted type value in the cast function. Are you indeed using MySQL ?

Comment: I am using SQL in Athena. Either way its `string`/`varchar`

Comment: Interestingly,  I replaced the `varchar` in the cast function with a permitted type value and did slight change to the `to_date` function which MySQL doesn't support. The query can be executed without fail in MySQL.

Comment: @blabla_bingo yes, MySQL has better support for correlated subqueries then Presto/Trino ATM.

Comment: @Guru Stron thanks for the insight, I shall pay attention to its correlated subqueries if I ever get to use Presto/Trino ATM : )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned in the [docs](https://trino.io/docs/current/sql/select.html#subqueries) correlated subqueries support is quite limited in Presto/Trino (SQL engine Athena is based on):

> Support for correlated subqueries is limited. Not every standard form is supported.

You can try working around via join and group by. If the combination of selected fields from t1 is unique then you can follow it with group by to get the results:

```sql
-- sample data
WITH table_1(id, year) as (
    values (1, 1),
        (2, 2),
        (3, 3)
),
table_2(id, year) as (
    values (1, 1),
        (1, 2),
        (1, 3),
        (2, -101)
)

-- query
select t1.id, t1.year, if(max(t2.id) is not null, 'something', 'something else')
from table_1 t1
left join table_2 t2 on t1.id = t2.id and t2.year between t1.year - 1 and t1.year + 1
group by t1.id, t1.year;
```

Output:

| id | year | _col2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2 | 2 | something else |
| 1 | 1 | something |
| 3 | 3 | something else |

Otherwise you will need to use synthesized unique id (for example using `row_number` window function). Something along these lines:

```sql
select arbitrary((t1.id, t1.year)).*, -- Trino ROW flattening trick to reduce amount of code
       if(max(t2.id) is not null, 'something', 'something else')
from (
    select *, 
           row_number() over() as unique_id 
    from table_1) t1
left join table_2 t2 
    on t1.id = t2.id and t2.year between t1.year - 1 and t1.year + 1
group by t1.unique_id;
```

Comment: You are a life saver! The first query worked for me. I tried a few things similar to that earlier but missed the group by!! Thank you so much!!!!!!! :D